# replace last element in array php

Tags: php, arrays

here an array

```
$item = new rssGenerator_item();
$query_rss = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `trades` WHERE `app` = '1' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10 ")OR die(mysql_error());
while($row_rss = mysql_fetch_array($query_rss)){
    $item->title = $row_rss['unit'];
    $item->description = excerpt($row_rss['message'],30);
    $item->link = 'http://injaa.com/'.$row_rss['link'];
    $item->guid = $row_rss['site'];
    $item->pubDate = RelativeTime($row_rss['tarikh']);
    $rss_channel->items[] = $item;
}
$rss_feed = new rssGenerator_rss();
$rss_feed->encoding = 'UTF-8';
$rss_feed->version = '2.0';
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo $rss_feed->createFeed($rss_channel);
```

at this line

```
$rss_channel->items[] = $item;
```

all value before this clear and replace last value into array!!
i dont now where is the code is wrong?

Comment: not sure what you're asking here. what do you expect it to do, and what is it actually doing?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php see the big red box? you should read it ;)

Comment: actually i want add element's into array with while loop and print array

Comment: Is `$rss_channel->items` even a valid property?  We can't see where you initialize the container object nor can we see what that object looks like.

Comment: @shahriyar3: if your problem is resolved. consider accepting best answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
array_push($rss_channel->items, $item);
```

At the top(before `while`) add

```
$rss_channel->items = array();
```

Comment: This will throw a warning if `$rss_channel->items` isn't already an array, whereas `$rss_channel->items[] = $item;` will initialize `$rss_channel->items` as an array if it isn't already; that part isn't necessarily wrong.

Comment: @MR Srinivas tnx for answer but is'nt work! in loop last item replace to all

Comment: @shahriyar3: No chance to replace. I think you logic is wrong use `foreach` instead of `while`

Answer (score 0):

Although @Mr Srinivas answer is better, personally I'd rewrite it like this:

```
$items = array();
while($row_rss = mysqli_fetch_array($query_rss)){
    $items[] = $item;
}
$rss_channel->items = $items;
```

Admittedly I don't have the knowledge to explain why this is better, this is just how it would make sense to me.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't recommend to use mysql_fetch_array. :) rather pdo or mysql functions

Comment: If `$rss_channel->items` is already an array, you're just adding an unnecessary step here.

Comment: @Robert yep quite right, though I only refactored the OP's code - have edited the answer.

Comment: @Crontab yes true, and I do think MR Srinivas answer is the correct one. Going on what the rather obfuscated OP asked, I thought there might have been some issue adding entries to the object's array so thought of using a variable to store them before adding to the object. I don't know enough to explain why or what but thought this might help narrow down the problem code.